# PHP: Filtering too hight and too low numbers in array

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I have an array like this: `102, 97, 101, 1, 107, 95, 555`.
I need to exclude numbers, which very differ from other. So array should be: `102, 97, 101, 107, 95`.
How can I do this in php?

Comment: 1) Have you tried something 2) What means/define *very differ from each other* ?

Comment: What will be criteria to identify too high or low?

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: This seems to be unclear did you defined the list of array that need to be excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getAverageArray($min, array $arr){
    $arr2 = array($arr[0]);
    foreach(array_slice($arr,1) as $val)
        if ($val - $arr[0] < $min && $arr[0] - $val < $min)
            $arr2[] = $val;
    return $arr2;
}

//the minimum difference necessary
$min = 90;
$arr = array(102, 97, 101, 1, 107, 95, 555);

//Array ( [0] => 102 [2] => 97 [3] => 101 [4] => 107 [5] => 95 )
print_r(getAverageArray($min,$arr));
```

Comment: These code work incorrect if the first number much higher then other. For example: `(999, 102, 97, 101, 1, 107, 95) -> (999)`

Comment: Well yes basically or you use the first key or you pass the average number, you could even compute them all...

Answer (score 0):

That's possible but you have to set the threshold.

1. get the average of all the values
2. exclude values whose `abs(value-avergage) > your_threshold``